# sum of all row values of one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, row

I am trying to find a function in R that does the same as `"SUM()"` in `Excel` .

I know there are similar questions, but I am having trouble applying them to my case (the other questions pose more complicated examples, and all I want is a simple sum).

I am able to go around this most of the times by using `lentgh(df$column)` and `length(unique(df$column))`, but in some cases it's not enough.

I have tried `sum(df$column)` but no luck, and neither with
 `this <- as.numeric(as.character(df$column))`then `sum(this)`

Ex

```
id    sex    age    source
12     M      NA     1
12     NA     3      1
13     NA     2      2
13     NA     NA     NA
13     F      2      NA
```

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L), sex = structure(c(2L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), age = c(NA, 
3L, 2L, NA, 2L), source = c(1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

and I want the sum of values of the column "source", so 4.

Comment: `sum(df$source, na.rm = TRUE)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: `sum(df$source, na.rm=TRUE)`. Most, if not all, R functions have `na.rm=FALSE` by default.